# How do i install Apache Modules in Windows 10 with Xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm trying to follow through with a tutorial on php but the tutor has a different environment to me. So I've been using Xampp to allow me to continue my php studies. The issue appears when I use CSS or JS content in my site. It's interpreted as text/html only. So i can't use either.

I confirmed that my chrome browser was interpreting my CSS and JS as text/html through a warning in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/public/css/style.css".
```

I know I need to install a module called Mod_Mime but I have no idea how to install Apache modules. The tutorials i could find were all in Linux based environments.

Comment: I know very little about `xampp`, but I _doubt_ that it does _not_ bundle that module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user arkascha had pointed out, he had doubts that xampp was not bundling the mod_mime module.

He is correct. I confirmed this through the xampp shell by typing the command:

```
httpd -M
```

This showed me all of my Loaded modules and `mime_module` is there. I can confirm that my understanding of my issue was not correct and i will look into alternate causes